# Map Matrix Returned by `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D`

Tags: opencv, matrix, rotation

I am looking at the `map_matrix` (i.e. a matrix operator) returned by
 the function `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D`. By my calculations, since the
 operator rotates an image about an arbitrary point and scales the
 matrix, the operator can be calculated as a translation by `(-x,-y)`,
 followed by a rotation, followed by a translation by `(+x,+y)`, then
 multiplied by scalar `k` like this:

> [image: eqn_line01]
>   [image: eqn_line02]
>   [image: eqn_line03]
>   [image: eqn_line04]

where `C = cos(theta)` and `S = sin(theta)`. (see [Rotation Matrix and
 of rotation around a
 point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093314/rotation-matrix-and-of-rotation-around-a-point)).
 This is close to what OpenCV lists in their documentation, but not
 quite the same (you can see the `k`/scale is not multiplied through
 the entire `(1-C)` term and the signs of the `beta`s are flipped:

> [image: eqn_OpenCV]

I do know that the rotation matrix is skew-symmetric because, if
 `theta` is a negative number, then since sine is an odd function, we
 would have

> [image: eqn_RotMtx]

in the above, but we would still not get the same result as shown by
 `OpenCV`. Am I missing something? Did I mess up somewhere in my derivation? How did `OpenCV` arrive at their equation?

Comment: @S.I. Thank you for reviewing my problem. Can you tell me if this question is more appropriate for MathStackExchange? Also, could you tell me what you deleted from the post and why my post was marked down?

Comment: Hey @A.Hendry. I didn't delete anything from the post. I just formatted it. About the downvotes I don't know who and why is downvoted it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone check me on this...

1. I forgot we were using **non-standard coordinates**. The rotation matrix as shown above is for Cartesian coordinates where `y` points "upward". However, in computer graphics, the y-axis points downards from the top left corner. (See "Non-standard orientation of the coordinate system" section on this Wikipedia link [Rotation matrix][1].)

[image: ImageCoordAxes]

As such, to make counter-clockwise rotation positive, **we do need to enter `-theta` in the rotation matrix.**

2. If we **swap `k` and `T(x,y)`** above, and **replace `k` by its homogeneous coordinates representation**, we would arrive at the correct equation. i.e., above I had `kI`, where `I` is the identity matrix. Instead, I should have used this

[image: HomgeneousCoords]

Homogeneous coordinates are necessary in computer graphics because we are making transformations on 2D points, but need to represent the operations as 3x3 matrices in order to make the mathematics work.

Lastly, drop the uncessary `[0 0 1]` row from the end result, and you get what OpenCV has. (You'd be multiplying a `2x3` matrix by a `3x1` point vector (i.e. `[x y 1].T`; remember homogeneous coordinates) to get a `2x1` output.